# How to import repeated function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a repeated piece of code, because I want to use the same function in two components (or more). How Can I import this in a good way, because my solution is not working well, I did this by import {repeatFunc} from "../functions/utilis"; After import function I want to show const {show} in both component

utilis.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "../styles.css";
import { leagues, teams } from "../data/data";

export const repeatFunc = () => {
  const [optionTeams, setOptionTeams] = useState([])
  const leagueOption = leagues.map((item) => <option>{item.name}</option>);

  let yourTeams = [];
  const showTeam = (e) => {
    const chosenLeague = e.target.value;
    teams.map((team) => {
      if (team.league === chosenLeague) {
        yourTeams.push(team.name);
        setOptionTeams(yourTeams);
      }
    });
    console.log(yourTeams);
  };
  const teamOption = optionTeams.map((team) => <option>{team}</option>);

  const show = (
    <>
      <div className="form-group">
        League:
        <select onChange={showTeam}>
          {leagueOption}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        Team One:
        <select>{teamOption}</select>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        Team Two:
        <select>{teamOption}</select>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Test.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "../styles.css";
import { leagues, teams } from "../data/data";
import {repeatFunc} from "../functions/utilis";

const Test = () => {
 
repeatFunc();

  return (
    <>
      <div className="card">
        Test
        <form>{show}</form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Card.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../styles.css";
import { leagues, teams } from "../data/data";
import { repeatFunc } from "../functions/utilis";
const Card = () => {
  repeatFunc();

  return (
    <>
      <div className="card">
        Card
        <form>{show}</form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Comment: You're close. Use `export const RepeatFunc` (that's called a functional component). Now insert `<RepeatFunc />` in your JSX somewhere else. Edit: right, you need to return the JSX at the end, not set `show` to it. (to be clear: you're already using this concept; both Test and Card are functional components. Now apply it to `repeatFunc`)

Comment: @ChrisG That's could be good, but what if I want to do next function in Test.js which will be using values from RepeatFunc? Then I think jsx return will be not working in good way, but I could be wrong

Comment: You need to decide whether you want a regular function that returns stuff or whether you want a function that will act as component. Regardless of that, simply calling `repeatFunc();` will not set variables like `show`. Note that in order to load and provide data, there's the concept of custom hooks. But as a React beginner, you should really stick to class components right now. That way it's much easier to distinguish between components and regular functions.

Comment: @ChrisG Ok, and f.e if I use it as JSX component <RepeatFunc> and send value f.e leagueOption as a props will be a good practice?